# $\int\frac{(2x+3)dx}{(x^2+2x+3)\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}}$

Tags: integration

$\int\frac{(2x+3)dx}{(x^2+2x+3)\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}}$

---

$I=\int\frac{(2x+3)dx}{(x^2+2x+3)\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}}=\int\frac{(2x+2)dx}{(x^2+2x+3)\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}}+\int\frac{1 dx}{(x^2+2x+3)\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}}$
Let first integral be called $I_1$ and the second integral be called $I_2$.
$I_1=\int\frac{dt}{t\sqrt{t+1}}$,where $x^2+2x+3=t$
$I_1=\int\frac{2dp}{p^2-1}$,where $p=\sqrt{t+1}$
$I_1=\log\frac{p-1}{p+1}=\log\frac{\sqrt{t+1}-1}{\sqrt{t+1}+1}=\log\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}-1}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}+1}+c$
But i could not find $I_2$,please help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** the following substitutions reduce the original integral into a pair of very familiar ones.

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\int\frac{2x+3}{\left(x^2+2x+3\right)\sqrt{x^2+2x+4}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int\frac{2y+1}{\left(y^2+2\right)\sqrt{y^2+3}}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{\left[x+1=y\right]}\\
&=\int\frac{2}{w^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}w;~~~\small{\left[\sqrt{y^2+3}=w\right]}\\
&~~~~~+\int\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{2+t^2};~~~\small{\left[\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+3}}=t\right]}.\\
\end{align}$$

I presume you can take it from there.